# Order details not saving to database in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, e-commerce

I am a beginner in django and i have been working on this ecommerce platform for a while now and i'm stuck in this place.

Whenever i fill order details form, it is not saving to the database.

Please i need your help

Here is the form

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2',
                  'country', 'state', 'city', 'order_note']
```

Here is the view for the place order:

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user

    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0

    for item in cart_items:
        total += (item.product.price * item.cart_quantity)
        quantity += item.cart_quantity

    tax = (3 * total) / 100
    grand_total = total + tax

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Order()
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

            # Save the data before generating the order number
            data.save()

            # Generate Order Number using the date, month, and day ordered
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr, mt, dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()

            return redirect('checkout')
        else:
            form = OrderForm()
        #return redirect('checkout')
        return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the html:

```
{% extends 'base/index.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<section class="section-content padding-y bg">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- ============================ COMPONENT 1 ================================= -->
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <article class="card mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Billing Address</h4>
                            <form action="{% url 'place_order' %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name"
                                            required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name"
                                            required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                                            placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"
                                            placeholder="+23476598577">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="address_line_1">Address Line 1</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_line_1"
                                            name="address_line_1" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="address_line_2">Address Line 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_line_2"
                                            name="address_line_2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="state">State</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="city">City</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="order_note">Order Note</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="order_note" name="order_note"
                                        rows="2"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Place
                                    Order</button>
                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
                    </article> <!-- card.// -->
                </div> <!-- card.// -->
            </aside> <!-- col.// -->
            <aside class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table class="table table-borderless table-shopping-cart">
                            <thead class="text-muted">
                                <tr class="small text-uppercase">
                                    <th scope="col">Product</th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="120">Quantity</th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="120">Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for cart_item in cart_items %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <figure class="itemside align-items-center">
                                            <div class="aside"><img src="{{ cart_item.product.image.url }}"
                                                    class="img-sm"></div>
                                            <figcaption class="info">
                                                <a href="{{cart_item.product.get_url}}"
                                                    class="title text-dark">{{cart_item.product.product_name}}</a>
                                                <p class="text-muted small">
                                                    {% if cart_item.variation.all %}
                                                    {% for item in cart_item.variation.all %}
                                                    {{ item.variation_category | capfirst }} : {{item.variation_value|capfirst }} <br>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </p>
                                            </figcaption>
                                        </figure>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="input-group input-spinner">
                                                <label>{{ cart_item.cart_quantity }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="price-wrap">
                                            <var class="price">${{ cart_item.sub_total }}</var>
                                            <small class="text-muted">${{ cart_item.product.price }} each</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <a href="{% url 'store' %}" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Continue Shopping</a>
                    </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
                </div> <!-- card.// -->
            </aside> <!-- col.// -->
        </div> <!-- row.// -->
        <!-- ============================ COMPONENT 1 END .// ================================= -->
    </div> <!-- container .//  -->
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

I have searched on Google for answers, it is still not working. I tried printing the id in the terminal, still not working.
Please how can i solve it. Thanks

Comment: what happens when you submit the form? any errors?

Comment: When do you overried the form when it is not valid ? `form = OrderForm()`. YOu should let it in contect and render forms errors in you're html. My guess is, there are errors in the post you POST but your construction does not let you know it.

Comment: Remove the `else: form = OrderForm()` part.

Comment: @NickLangat no errors when I submit the form. The product and the form inputs clear off when I submit the form. But when I go to the admin to check the order information, nothing is there.

Comment: @Alombaros how do I do the construction? Is there anything wrong with the views?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that, it return an error while I wanted to submit the form.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to use the example Django provided https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView